# Can I serialize a struct camel_case and deserialize PascalCase in Rust

Tags: rust, serde

I have a struct I want to be able to serialize in camel_case and deserialize in PascalCase. Is this possible? I've seen the serde `rename_all = snake_case`

Comment: Why would you want that?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I've done something like this before to use the same type definition in multiple places that use different conventions (accept data from external API but feed directly into some internal service). But in my experience that idea is often shortsighted and I end up using separate structs anyway.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [the docs](https://serde.rs/container-attrs.html#rename_all):

> ###### `#[serde(rename_all = "...")]`
>
> Rename all the fields (if this is a struct) or variants (if this is an enum) according to the given case convention. The possible values are `"lowercase"`, `"UPPERCASE"`, `"PascalCase"`, `"camelCase"`, `"snake_case"`, `"SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE"`, `"kebab-case"`, `"SCREAMING-KEBAB-CASE"`.
>
> Allows specifying independent cases for serialization vs deserialization:
>
> - `#[serde(rename_all(serialize = "..."))]`
> - `#[serde(rename_all(deserialize = "..."))]`
> - `#[serde(rename_all(serialize = "...", deserialize = "..."))`

So `#[serde(rename_all(serialize = "camelCase", deserialize = "PascalCase"))]`